# My Obj is not loading while iam trying to give path from project folder

Tags: javascript, three.js, objloader

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js';

// Create a scene, camera, and renderer
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(65, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 800);
camera.position.z = 5;
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Lighting
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040); // Soft white light
scene.add(ambientLight);
const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
directionalLight.position.set(0, 1, 0); // Adjust as needed
scene.add(directionalLight);

// Create an instance of OBJLoader
const loader = new OBJLoader();

// Specify the path to your .obj file and ensure it's correct and accessible
loader. Load (
    '../src/assets/models/test.obj', // Make sure this path is correct!
    function (object) { // This function is called after the object is loaded
        scene.add(object); // Add the loaded object to the scene
        console.log('OBJ file loaded successfully.');

        object.position.set(0, 0, 0); // Adjust as necessary
        object.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01); // Adjust as necessary
        camera.lookAt(object.position);

        // Traverse the object to modify materials
        object.traverse(function(child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                child.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ wireframe: true });
                child.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide; // Make the material double-sided
            }
        });

        animate(); // Start animation loop after the model is loaded
    },
    function (xhr) { // Optional: Progress callback
        console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
    },
    function (error) { // Error callback
        console.error('An error happened:', error);
    }
);

// Animation loop
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

I'm trying to import the obj to my viewer which im not able to. 'm thinking it is because of path which is on the project folder

I am getting a black screen.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi, so you just opening html file? For accesing file you need some webserver, where is files hosted. Browser can't open local files. 

Edit: I check image, you using some local host, is path to file ok? Maybe you can some public obj. First try not load object, but create some sphere, or cube. You will see if your code work.

Answer (score 0):

Your obj is loaded. Try set scale it more. If i would have to guess, has red color... Look at scale:

```
object.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
```

Make it bigger

```
object.scale.set(2, 2, 2);
```

[image]